# Related to the property of Hypergeometric function

Tags: recurrence-relations, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Is there any property of Hypergeometric function due to which we can show that $$\frac{x^{km+2}(a+x^k)^{1-m}}{a(km+2)}\,_2F_1\left(1,\frac{k+2}{k};\frac{2}{k}+m+1;-\frac{x^k}{a}\right)=\frac{1}{km+2}\frac{1}{a^m}x^{km+2}\,_2F_1\left(m+\frac{2}{k},m,m+1+\frac{2}{k};-\frac{x^k}{a}\right)$$ where $a,m$ are greater than zero and $k>2$. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Using Euler's transformation it can be done very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: From the third formula for linear transformation http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1 you have
$${_2F_1}\left(1,1+\frac{2}{k},\frac{2}{k}+m+1, -\frac{x^k}{a}\right)$$
$$= \left(1-\frac{x^k}{a}\right)^{\frac{2}{k}+m+1-1-(1+\frac{2}{k})} {_2F_1}\left(\frac{2}{k}+m+1-1,\frac{2}{k}+m+1-1-\frac{2}{k},\frac{2}{k}+m+1, -\frac{x^k}{a}\right)
$$
$$= \left(1-\frac{x^k}{a}\right)^{m-1}{_2F_1}\left(m+\frac{2}{k},m,\frac{2}{k}+m+1, -\frac{x^k}{a}\right)
$$
which shows already the correct arguments. Now check if the quotient of your factors match (actually this form looks simpler than the one one from the question.)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I think Euler transformation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) can also be used.